# Printing std::this_thread::get_id() gives "thread::id of a non-executing thread"?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread

This used to work perfectly fine (and then aliens must have hacked my PC):

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and now it prints `thread::id of a non-executing thread`.

ideone.com prints some ID, but it's interesting what may have caused this behavior on my platform.

```
$ uname -a
Linux xxx 3.13.0-77-generic #121-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 20 10:50:42 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any ideas?

---

EDIT: Well.. when I add

```
std::cout << pthread_self() << std::endl;
```

**both** lines print the same ID, but when I remove it, the result is still the same - "non-executing thread".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a side-effect of a glibc feature, fixed in  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57060:

```
// For the GNU C library pthread_self() is usable without linking to
// libpthread.so but returns 0, so we cannot use it in single-threaded
// programs, because this_thread::get_id() != thread::id{} must be true.
```

If you explicitly link against pthreads (`-pthread` or `-lpthread`) then your program will behave as expected.

Oddly enough, on my system, adding a call to `pthread_self` (before or after the call to `std::this_thread::get_id()` does not change behavior:

```
0
thread::id of a non-executing thread
```

This may be an Ubuntu-specific behavior, linking pthreads automatically if `pthread_self` is called, but it seems a bit odd. Note that `std::this_thread::get_id()` calls `pthread_self` via a weak reference (itself via `__gthread_self`).

Comment: Oh, that's brilliant, exactly what I wanted to understand! And yeah, I'm positive that this is exactly what have happend to me - the linkage with `pthread`. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Standard does not actually define what the `this_thread::get_id` is going to return. All it says is:

> Returns: An object of type thread::id that **uniquely identifies the
>   current thread of execution. No other thread of execution shall have
>   this id and this thread of execution shall always have this id**. The
>   object returned shall not compare equal to a default constructed
>   thread::id.

This condition is met with your output, so everything is in order.

By the way, do not confuse `thread_id` returned by `this_thread::get_id` with numerical thread id returned by `std::thread::get_id()`. `thread_id` main usage is to be compared and used in associative containers, not directly introspected or printed.

Comment: `std::thread::get_id()` returns the same `std::thread::id` type as `std::this_thread::get_id()`.